# Make the numbers 1-50 using 2, 0, 2, 0

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Make the numbers 1-50 using 2 0 2 0 in the given order. Use all four digits exactly once.

Allowed operations: +, -, x, /, ! (factorial), double factorial, exponentiation, square root, parentheses. Grouping (e.g. "20") is also allowed, as are decimals (e.g. ".2").

Comment: Is squaring also a valid operation? What is the scoring mechanism to determine the "best" answer?

Comment: Squaring is not a valid operation.

Comment: Can you group the like this: 0! grouped with 2 makes 12?

Comment: @Duck, no grouping like this!

Comment: If we allow other functions we can put: $\left \lfloor 20^{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}} \right \rfloor - 0!$ or $-2+.0\bar{2}^{-0!}$ or $-\Gamma(2)+.0\bar{2}^{-0!}$.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone is welcome to edit and improve this answer, so don't checkmark this answer.
Bolded numbers mean they need to be solved or are impossible.

1

> $(2+0-2)+0!$

2

> $2+(0*2)+0$

3

> $2+0!+(2*0)$

4

> $2+0+2+0$

5

> $2+0!+2+0$

6

> $2+0!+2+0!$

7

> $(2+(0!))*2)+0!$

8

> $2*(0!+2+0!)$

9

> $(2+0!)*(2+0!)$

10

> $(20/2+0)$

11

> $(20/2+0!)$

12

> $(2+0!)!*2+0$

13

> $((2+0!)!*2)+0!$

14

> $20-((2+0!)!)$

15

> $(2+0!)/.20$

16

> $(2+0!)/.2+0!$

17

> $20-2-0!$

18

> $20-2+0$

19

> $20-2+0!$

20

> $20+2*0$

21

> $2-0!+20$

22

> $20+2+0$

23

> $20+2+0!$

24

> $(2+0+2+0)!$

25

> $((2*0!)*2)!+0!$

26

> $20+((2+0!)!)$

27

> $(2+0!)^{(2+0!)}$

28

> $((2+0!)!)!!-20$

29

> $((2+0!)!/.2)-0!$

30

> $((2+0!)!/.2)+0$

31

> $((2+0!)!/.2)+0!$

32

> $2^{((0!+2)!-0!)}$

33

> $2^{((0!/.2))}+0!$

**34**

> 

35

> $(2+0!)!^2-0!$

36

> $(2+0!)!^2+0$

37

> $(2+0!)!^2+0!$

38

> $2(-0!+20)$

39

> $20*2-0!$

40

> $20+20$

41

> $(20*2)+0!$

42

> $2*(0!+20)$

**43**

> 

**44**

> 

45

> $((2+0!)!)!!-2-0!$

46

> $((2+0!)!)!!-2+0$

47

> $((2+0!)!)!!-2+0!$

48

> $2*(0!+2+0!)!$

49

> $((2+0!)!)!!+2-0!$

50

> $((2+0!)!)!!+2+0$

Comment: I have a premonition that 50 is going to be impossible. Good on you for keeping at it, though: +1

Comment: @Avi, this is the second time you've undone my edit, with more progress than you've made. Please undo. I did 11-25.

Comment: @DonThousand 11-25 are done.

Comment: That was earlier - Don found 23-25 before you did, and I found them at about the same time as you

Comment: @Avi Oh, well are 27-28 even possible?

Comment: Not sure - it's pretty tough to get off of 2 and 0 as the only numbers, *with* ordering restrictions

Comment: @AndrejJakobčič Clever 27, nice!

Comment: If anyone is welcome to improve this answer, it's better to mark it community wiki.

Comment: @Glorfindel I agree, since Avi and I did significant parts of this.

Comment: Great! I was thinking the same thing!

Comment: Double factorial is useful: 6!!=48

Comment: @AndrejJakobčič You didn't specify this was allowed.

Comment: @DonThousand I believe that factorial include double factorial.

Comment: No, double factorial is different. In any case, I edited it into the question.